# docopt in R returning the same script

Tags: r, shell, arguments, docopt

I am fairly new using `docopt` for passing arguments in R.

I have something like this:

```
#!/n/tools/script
##First read in the arguments listed at the command line
library(docopt)
require(methods)

"
Usage:
  Finding.R [options] FILE

  Description:   
  Options:
   --help                        Show this screen
   --version                     Show the current version.
   --Threshold=<Threshold>       [default: 250]
   --output=OUTPUT               [default: out.txt]
   --color=<color>               [default: FALSE]
  Arguments:
   FILE  The tree file
  " -> doc

  opt <- docopt(doc)
```

The first 2 lines are from a previous code, and the rest is about my current work.

My problem is that when I run it,

```
Finding.R --Threshold 250 INPUT
```

instead of a warning, error or something coherent, I just get the same script in another window, like nothing happened. I thought it was a problem of my options, but then I tried:

```
Finding.R --help
```

And nothing happened.

Could someone shed some light on this? Surely I am doing something wrong, but after looking around in a lot of webpages I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Do you know what the program /n/tools/script does? For the code to be executed, I'd expect your shebang (i.e. #!) line to be pointing to R or Rscript (e.g. #!/bin/Rscript).

Comment: My boss sent it to me, apparently is not an Rscript but an executable? I do really don't know how the shebang works so I am kind of lost here

Comment: that first line, starting with a #!, tells the system what program should be used to intepret the code below. My GUESS is that /n/tools/script simply displays the code rather than executing it. If you are running UNIX and can execute Rscript straight from the command line, use "which Rscript" to determine where Rscript lives and use the output in your #! line. I am not sure this is the issue, but it is what I'd try.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried and still I get the same. I am clueless about what might be happening

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential issues here. The first is that you are probably not invoking R; the second is that you are not doing anything with the options you've parsed. Heres a simple example: note that we invoke Rscript on the first line, and that we print the parsed options on the last.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript 

library(docopt)
"Usage:
  Finding.R [options]

Options:
--Threshold=<Threshold>       [default: 250]
--output=OUTPUT               [default: out.txt]
--color=<color>               [default: FALSE]
" -> doc

opt <- docopt(doc)
print(opts)
```

At the command line:

```
chmod +x Finding.R
./Finding.R
$`--Threshold`
[1] "250"

$`--output`
[1] "out.txt"

$`--color`
[1] "FALSE"

$Threshold
[1] "250"

$output
[1] "out.txt"

$color
[1] "FALSE"
```